# Can't link my css file to html

Tags: html, css

Please help, i really cannot see what i am doing wrong. I have tried all permutations and still cannot link so have started to write css code in html. Not what i want to do. Been looking at it too long and hoping someone can see my error. Thnks

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
      </head>
```

My file tree is my directory folder name of the project then a sub folder css, then the style.css

Comment: where is path html file and css file?

Comment: Can you provide a visual of the tree?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<link href="../css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

OR

```
<link href="/ProjectName/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your index file is in the root directly below the css file, you need to write "./css/style.css" - you're definitely not pointing to the right location.

```
<link href="./css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to link to your stylesheet and it is not working, navigate to your stylesheet (it should look like http://www.example.com/css/style.css) and then copy the URL to your `<link rel="stylesheet">` tag so it looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.example.com/css/style.css">
```

instead of this:

```
<link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Hope this helps!